# path category and classifying space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory

Let $\mathbf{Top}$ be the category of topological spaces and continuous maps, and $\mathbf{Cat}$ be the category of small categories and functors.

There is a **path functor** $\mathcal{P}:\mathbf{Top}\to \mathbf{Cat}$, which takes a topological space $X$ to its path category $\mathcal{P}(X)$ with points of $X$ as objects and  unparametrised directed paths as morphisms. There is also a **classifying functor** $\mathcal{G}:\mathbf{Cat}\to \mathbf{Top}$, which sends a small category $C$ to its classifying space $\mathcal{G}(C)$. Here the classifying space is the standard definition $\mathcal{G}(C)=|\mathbf{N}(C)|$, that is, the geometric realization of the nerve of $C$.

My questions are:

1. For any topological space $X$, are $X$ and $\mathcal{G(P}(X))$ homotopically equivalent?
2. For any small category $C$, what is the relation of $C$ and $\mathcal{P(G}(C))$?
3. What is the precise relation between $\mathcal{P}$ and $\mathcal{G}$.

Comment: 1. would be better stated with "weakly equivalent" instead of "homotopy equivalent" since $X$ might not be of the homotopy type of a CW complex (but the classifying space of category is a CW complex).

Comment: Does $\mathcal P$ see homotopies between paths in any way? If not, then isn't $\pi = \pi_1(\mathcal G(\mathcal P(\mathbf R^2)),0)$ uncountably generated? Any two distinct loops at $0$ in $\mathbf R^2$ give elements of $\pi$, which have no chance of becoming identified with your definitions.

Comment: Following @R.vanDobbendeBruyn's comment, you really need to make it an $\infty$-category (even an $\infty$-groupoid), and then it's really just singular simplices and you do get a weak equivalence. 

Comment: @DaveBenson I don't think I know what an unparameterised singular simplex is... (I'm not even certain there's a canonical meaning for unparameterised path. Do reparametrizations have to be monotone?)

Comment: an unparameterised path in topological space $X$ is an equivalence class of paths $\gamma:[0,1]\to X$, where the equivalence relation is given by the diffeomorphisms of the closed interval $[0,1]$. @Dan Ramras

Comment: All diffeomorphisms? But then a path doesn’t have a well defined start and end point. Does that even work? Seems like it makes loop composition commutative, for instance.

Comment: not all diffeomorphisms， but all orientation preserving diffeomorphisms，or equivalently those keeping the end points 0,1 fixed.